# How to show stack trace in uncaught java exception message when using forkJoinPool

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

When I have an uncaught exception in an instance of a recursiveTask (from [forkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)). the JVM prints a single line of error message telling me the type of the exception,

```
XXX.XXX.XXXXXXException
```

but without stack trace. With some testing, I realized that when there is **only one** instance of recursiveTask present in the forkJoinPool (i.e. by setting the **sThreshold** from the example in the link sufficiently large), the stack trace is always printed; with **multiple** instances present, there is no stack trace. The question is, how can I always get the stack trace?

### Follow-up:

an attempt to use the third constructor for forkJoinPool

```
private static final ForkJoinPool threadPool = 
new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 
defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, 
new ExceptionHandler(), false);
```

The ExceptionHandler class:

```
final class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    ExceptionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable err) {
        System.err.println("Uncaught " + err + " in thread " + t);
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The pool is invoked.

```
threadPool.invoke(new aForkJoinTask());
...
threadPool.invoke(new differentForkJoinTask());
```

Somewhere in the RecursiveAction I put in

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("word");
```

However, **solely** the following is printed as an error message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Meanwhile the same uncaught exception in the main thread prints a stack trace.

Comment: Can you paste some code that can show what are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not tried but IMO you can use the following [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html):

```
ForkJoinPool(int parallelism, ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory, Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler, boolean asyncMode)
```

It provides an option to declare the handler for internal worker threads that terminate due to unrecoverable errors encountered while executing tasks.

Comment: Is there a default implementation of Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler interface that one could readily use?